# Where can I find DB regional ticket maps (Streckenkarte)?

Tags: trains, germany, train-stations, deutsche-bahn

Usually, Deutsche Bahn offers a map (*Streckenkarte*) of various regional transport similar to this one for [Baden-Württemberg](https://www.mfo.de/for-guest-researchers/prepare-your-stay/Streckenkarte-BW-2013.pdf). Could anyone let me know where I can find it for Berlin-Brandenburg ticket? Also, maps for other regional routes would be nice. I want them as official maps either directly from the Deutsche Bahn or other trusted sources.

Comment: You mean [this map for Brandenburg](http://www.bahnstatistik.de/Strecken/StrR-Bln-Brd.pdf) complemented by [this map for Berlin](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/static/shop/pdf/vbb.pdf)?

Comment: Perfect. How do we find it on Google? I have been trying for several minutes without much success? Is there a database of other maps as well?

Comment: See my answer. It turned up very high when googling "Streckenkarte Berlin Brandenburg"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find these maps for all German "Länder" on [this DB site.](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/service/fahrplaene/streckennetz.shtml)

The one for Berlin-Brandenburg is found [here](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/mdb/bahnintern/angebotsberatung/regio/regionale_tickets/2018/mdb_266297_171210_bb_sa_s_171106_2.pdf). You may be used to the other look of the maps (like the BW one you link to), but apparently this is the new look for Berlin/Brandenburg at least. You can find an out-of-date version (as of 2007) [here](http://www.bahnstatistik.de/Strecken/StrR-Bln-Brd.pdf) if you insist.